# Forgot to delete model objects before altering model fields in models.py

Tags: django, django-models

I am getting this error continuously when I try to open this database through django admin

Exception Type: OperationalError at /admin/tasks/task/
Exception Value: no such column: tasks_task.task_name_id

Initially I changed a lot a fields in models which already had some objects stored. Now I couldnt have gone back so i started a new app and copied all the files from old app as they were in the same project. deleted the old app and renamed the new app by the name of old one so that in the project wherever refrenced there wont be any problem.

but now whenever i try to migrate i get this error:

```
File "C:\Users\sarda\anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 326, in check_constraints
    raise utils.IntegrityError(
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'tasks_task' with primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key: tasks_task.task_name_id cont
ains a value 'task_name_id' that does not have a corresponding value in tasks_task_list.id.
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
class Task_List(models.Model):
    task_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    c1=models.CharField(max_length=30, default="OTHER")
    c2=models.CharField(max_length=30, default="OTHER")
    c3=models.CharField(max_length=30, default="OTHER")
    time_esc=models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.task_name

class Task_manager(models.Manager):
    def create_Task(self, title,deadline):
        Task1 = self.create(title=title,deadline=deadline)
        # do something with the book
        return Task1  
class Task(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
       ('ONGOING', 'ONGOING'),
       ('COMPLETED','COMPLETED'),
       ('PENDING','PENDING' ),
       ('FINISHED','FINISHED')
   )

    task_name=models.ForeignKey(Task_List, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=30,default="Other", blank=True)
    created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    deadline_fixed=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    deadline=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    score=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    score_fixed=models.IntegerField(default=0, editable=False)
    status=models.CharField(max_length=15,default="ONGOING",choices=STATUS)
    stage=models.CharField(max_length=15, default='NORMAL')
    objects=Task_manager()
    class Meta:
        ordering = [ '-created']
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy
# Register your models here.
from .models import *
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import *

from searchableselect.widgets import SearchableSelect


def mark_completed(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    refresh(modeladmin,request,queryset)
    tasks=Task.objects.all()
    form=TaskForm()
    for task in tasks:
        if task.status=='ONGOING' and timezone.now()<task.deadline:
            queryset.update(status='COMPLETED')
        elif task.status=="PENDING":
            queryset.update(status='FINISHED')
            #row_completed=queryset.update(status='FINISHED')
        '''message_bit = "%s stories were" % row_completed
        self.message_user(request, "%s successfully marked as published." % message_bit)'''
mark_completed.short_description = "Mark COMPLETED"


def refresh(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    tasks=Task.objects.all()
    form=TaskForm()
    for task in tasks:
        if task.status=="ONGOING" and task.deadline<timezone.now():
            queryset.update(status='PENDING')
refresh.short_description = "Refresh"




class TaskAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    '''def film_status(self, obj):
        if obj.status == 'FINISHED':
            return '<div style="width:100%%; height:100%%; background-color:Green;">%s</div>' % obj.status()
        return obj.status()
    film_status.allow_tags = True'''
    form=TaskForm
    list_display=('task_name','title','status','deadline')
    list_filter=('status',)
    search_fields=('title',)
    date_hierarchy='created'
    actions=[refresh,mark_completed]
    radio_fields={'status': admin.HORIZONTAL}
    list_editable=['status',]
    #raw_id_fields=('c2',)
    #auto_complete=['title']
    '''fieldsets=[
    ['Basic', {
        'fields': ['comment','status']}],
    ['Advanced', {
        'classes': ['collapse'],
        'fields': [('created','deadline_fixed'),('c1', 'c2','c3'),('score_fixed','score')],
    }],]'''
    readonly_fields = ['score','score_fixed','deadline_fixed','created']
    def change_view(self,request,object_id,extra_content=None):
         return super(TaskAdmin,self).change_view(request,object_id)

admin.site.register(Task,TaskAdmin)
```

Comment: I think with `task_name=models.ForeignKey(Task_List, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)` you deleted an entry and now your list can't find the id that is looking for.

Comment: @GiorgosKavalieratos I just added that field, and deleted some other fields. I dont know how I can access the old database now and delete all these objects

Comment: As of Now I set the entire fields to old format, deleted all migrations and made it work. But if there is any other better solution I'll be glad to know.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sqlite and don't want to do everything with command line, you can access it with [DB Browser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/).